# Meromorphic function with given principle part

Tags: complex-analysis

Need to find meromorphic function with poles at $z=\sqrt{n}$ and principle part is $\frac{1}{(z-\sqrt{n})^4}+\frac{1}{z-\sqrt{n}}$ . It's clear that the first term would converge uniformly on the compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ because in comparison with $\frac{1}{n^2}$. But adding $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is not changing the convergence of the second term. Any hints regarding how to claim the convergence of the series ?

Comment: Simply taking $\sum_{n=1,2,3,\ldots} {1\over z-\sqrt{n}}$ does not succeed... Look at the proof of the Mittag-Loeffler theorem to see the devices necessary when the poles are "too close together".

Comment: Yes that's what I mentioned. I am not getting exactly what error term needs to be added in order to get succeeded.

Comment: The proof of the Mittag-Loeffler theorem is a little tricky! I could not easily reproduce it just now, on short notice! Find a source. (My own complex analysis notes do this...)

Comment: @paulgarrett: It is Mittag-Leffler :)

Comment: @MartinR, ah!!! My whole life I'd been mis-spelling! :) Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to develop the wanted principal parts into a Taylor series and take “sufficiently many” terms to that the rest converges locally uniformly.

In our case we have
$$
 \frac{1}{z-\sqrt{n}} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{\sqrt n} + \frac{z^2}{n} + \cdots\right)
$$
so that
$$
\frac{1}{z-\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt n} + \frac{z}{n} = O\left( \frac{z^2}{n^{3/2}}\right)
$$

This shows that
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z-\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt n} + \frac{z}{n}
$$
converges uniformly on each compact set not containing any of the poles. Combining that with your result we get
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-\sqrt{n})^4} + \frac{1}{z-\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt n} + \frac{z}{n}
$$
as a meromorphic function with the desired poles and principal parts.

Comment: Would not it be $ \frac{1}{z-\sqrt{n}} +\frac{z}{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}?$ In order to get the order of $\frac{z^2}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$?

Comment: @User1729: Yes, my fault.

Comment: No thanks. Actually I was thinking about this way only but I was not sure what exactly to add.